# Jquery to update inputbox after clone

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal, jquery-traversing

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$(".dispadd").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#hiddenrow')
        .clone()
            .removeAttr('id')
            .show()
            .appendTo( $('#disptable').after().show() 
    );
});
});
```

Works great to copy a table row containing form controls from one table to another.  My question is now, how do I update one of the form input fields as it is being added to its new table?  The form input I need to update (type=text) has a name and id of cat.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$('#hiddenrow')
        .clone()
            .removeAttr('id').find('#cat').val('newvalue').end()
            .show()
            .appendTo( $('#disptable').after().show() 
);
```

See working [**demo**](https://tinker.io/93a58)

Comment: The `shows()` are only needed if those elements were hidden (i.e. `display: none`) by some css rule, if not you can avoid them.

Comment: Your code seems to work great!  If I "Show Form Details", I can see the new value.  BUT, when I submit the form, the new value is not getting picked up by the form processor...

Comment: HA! My bad... I have all the form control names set as arrays, but forgot to add the [] to my cloned control.  Added it and now works great!  Thanks Nelson for your help!